# Activity destroyed, cannot dispatch event from contained fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity for user registration. At some point, in that activity I have a fragment with registration form. When user click **REGISTER** button I have a an event dispatched with event bus like this

In **RegistrationFragment** (contained in **RegistrationActivity**)

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new RegistrationSuccessfulEvent());
```

In **RegistrationActivity**

```
public void onEvent(RegistrationSuccessfulEvent event) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

I get this exception

```
Could not dispatch event: class com.myapp.RegistrationSuccessfulEvent to subscribing class class com.myapp.RegistrationActivity ... 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
```

Why I get activity destroyed? Is it possible that if activity A contains a fragment F that activity is terminated while F is still up and running? I thought that A is alive while F is alive or any other contained fragment is in running state. I'm quite confused about activity-fragment coupling lifecycle.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. But I am not sure what is creating the problem. I have a fragment, dashboard fragment, inside a main activity, from where I dispatch an event, some time when I start and restart the app it crashes with the above message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "alive" you mean "created but not yet destroyed", the activity lifecycle does not depend on inner fragments, though the inverse might stand.

It is possible that at that point the fragment has been destroyed (in the lifecycle meaning), but it's still an instance of a java class that has not been yet garbage collected. If so, it has still the chance to post the `Event`. In a strict sense, for example, `Activity has been destroyed` doesn't mean that its instance has been collected - it just went through the destroy process.

It is also possible that you are using [setRetainInstance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)) on your fragment, which allows keeping the fragment instance alive while the activity recreates.

In any case, to know why your RegistrationActivity is being destroyed more code is needed. It is possibly a configuration change, like changing orientation, or some other call you are making.

Comment: By alive I meant in **Active** state, after **onResume()** has been called. In my understanding while Activity has **Active** fragments within it should be **Active**. I might want to get some data from that activity while within fragment. So, are you saying that Fragment can be in **Active** state while it's activity in **Destroyed** state?

Comment: No, I'm saying that a non active class (be it Activity or Fragment or any other lifecycle-based android class) can still can methods until it is garbage collected. From an android standpoint they die `onDestroy`, but there can be a little (hopefully) time in which their instance is not null yet.

Comment: So, just to be sure. If Fragment is active then it's activity is also active, is that right?

Comment: Right, but calling EventBus.post() from the fragment doesn't mean it is "active". However I'm speaking generally here and I can't know what's really happening in your case. It might even be a bug in the library you are using.

Comment: Actually is exactly what I looked for. You answered my question already. I will figure out what I'm doing wrong. If not, I will post new question with more specific issues. Thanks!